# echo -e working improperly in shell script

Tags: shell, echo

I am using following script for the file which has a format that looks something like this:

```
    abc efg|hig
    yxf xnc
    xbs xnd|shc|ehc|xoc
```

and I want the output as something like this:

```
    abc efg
    abc hig
    yxf xnc
    xbs xnd
    xbs shc
    xbs ehc
    xbs xoc
```

and the script is as follows:

```
    while read line
    do
    line1=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    line2=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    arr=$(echo $line2 | tr "|" "\n")
    for x in $arr
    do
    echo -e "$x \t$line1\n"
    done
    done < FBC.txt
```

However I am getting the results which are mixing both the variables.Something like :

```
    abefgch
    abc hig
    yxxncf
    xxndbs
    xbs shc
    xbehcs
    xbs xoc
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include the actual output your code is producing and point out why it's wrong?

Comment: Isn't `echo -e "$x \t$line1\n"` backwards? Don't you mean `echo -e "$line1 \t$x\n"`? Also this could be done with a single awk script more easily than this.

Comment: `echo -e` printing anything other than `-e` is *itself* incorrect according to the POSIX specification. That GNU breaks spec in this way (in bash, and the `echo` provided by coreutils) is perhaps one of their more egregious / visible violations. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for discussion.

Comment: Anyhow -- there's a lot wrong with this code. To start with, your `arr` variable isn't actually an array, and `echo $line2` is very much not the same as `echo "$line2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it completely in awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    n = split($2, a, "|");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%s %s\n", $1, a[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at interpreting your intent into a correct script targeting POSIX sh (if you're actually targeting ksh, bash, or zsh, you could use arrays rather than overwriting the argument list):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f

while unset IFS; read -r line1 line2 rest; do
  IFS='|'
  for x in $line2; do
    printf '%s \t%s\n' "$x" "$line1"
  done
done <FBC.txt
```

Important notes:

- `set -f` makes this safe with data that could match files as wildcards.
- `unset IFS` before the first `read` sets the input field separator to its default value, splitting line1 and line2 variables by spaces or tab characters. (Content following the "line2" variable goes into the "rest" variable, which is unused).
- `IFS='|'` after that point ensures that `for x in $line2` splits by pipe characters.
- Using `printf` rather than `echo` ensures that your script doesn't depend on behavior that diverges from the POSIX specification.

Comment: It's still giving the same output also it is cutting the first alphabet of the new row in column1, something like befgch instead of abefgch etc

Comment: It does nothing of the sort. See this exact code running -- and behaving correctly -- in a sandbox with the exact input you gave in your question at http://ideone.com/bImumr; perhaps your input file has hidden characters in it? If you had a DOS-format text file with CRLFs, for instance, that could do what you're describing.

Comment: Sure let me try it again, Thanks!

Comment: If that does turn out to be the problem (and running `dos2unix` on the input file fixes things), I'd guess that the relevant difference between my answer and Marc's is is that awk implicitly treats LFs as whitespace.